Early theories about columnar jointing
Columnar jointing occurs frequently in igneous rocks. The phenomenon is now understood to happen by thermal contraction of a cooling mass of lava (or ashes, in the case of columnar ignimbrites). I've managed to retrace the evolution of ideas about their origin during the 18th and 19th centuries, until Irish geologist Robert Mallet (1875) seems to have definitely solved the matter. I also know some legends that tried to "explain" columnar jointing in early times, like bear scratches on Devils Tower, and of course the Giant's Causeway being built by... a giant.
Now I would like to find something in-between: texts from the Renaissance maybe, that would not be legends, but rather early attempts at explaining columnar jointing in a kind of scientific way. These theories would probably be very wrong, and involve elemental powers, like the theories of volcanism of the time, which often involved subterranean winds... If you know some texts of this period mentioning columnar jointing and its formation, please feel free to share them!

The "Gyants Cawsway" depicted in A New Map of Ireland Divided into its Provinces, Counties and Baronies, by cartographer Hermal Moll (1714). From Gallica, public domain.

Montgomery in The Eye and the Rock mentions "an early drawing of columnar basalt from Conrad Gessner's De Rerum Fossilium, Lapidum et Gemmarum (1565), showing a "mineralogical" interpretation of these features as quartz-type crystals." Apparently, Leonardo painted columnar joints too, in Virgin of the Rocks, but without explanations, see Pizzorusso, Leonardo's Geology.

@Conifold Great find, thanks! I managed to find a copy at the Biodiversity Heritage Library (pp. 20-23). The drawing is a bit fantasist, some columns having pointy ends, like crystals... The text cites Agricola, who indeed wrote about columnar basalt in his De Natura Fossilium (1546), mentioning the site of Stolpen Castle, with even some considerations on the number of faces (from four to seven). Cool stuff!
